# Webhook not performing subscription validation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are creating a Webhook/Subscription using Microsoft Graph. However, the following JSON is returned and we can see no corresponding HTTP request to our validation public web server:

```json
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Subscription validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "d2c4eeca-1bf9-4657-a904-ba6925428bbd",
        "date": "2018-02-24T17:19:56"
    }
}
```

Our HTTP POST request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions` contains this JSON:

```json
{
    "changeType": "created,updated",
    "clientState": "subscription-identifier",
    "expirationDateTime": "2018-02-27T15:46:18.835Z",
    "notificationUrl": "https://[public_web_server]/api/watl/o365",
    "resource": "Users/[email address]/mailfolders('inbox')/messages"
}
```

When testing the request via `Hurl.it` and other online HTTP requests we can see the request hit our web server. However, we can not see anything coming from Microsoft Graph.

Our web server is responding with a `200 OK` and including the `ValidationToken` as the body.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you setting as the `content-type` in your validation response? Also, have you confirmed that the `User` in question has a valid mailbox (i.e. calling `/users/{id}/mailfolders('inbox')/messages` returns results)?

Comment: Hi Marc, If I run the call via Graph Explorer "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/{id}/mailfolders('inbox')/messages" it returns the emails. The content type of the subscription call is application/json, and the verification is "text/plain". What I find odd is no actual request comes in from the Graph servers? However, the public server is accessible.

Comment: If it helps - here is the header of the verification response. Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sun, 25 Feb 2018 09:23:32 GMT
Server: ServiceNow
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Is-Logged-In: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be happening because the notification URL provided in the request payload does not accept media type "text/plain". Can you make the change and try again?

Comment: Hi - I’ve added this as accepted inbound request format, hasn’t changed error? Thanks

Comment: You star! It did work, just exposed another issue which is fixed. Many thanks :)