# Graph subscription errors on Validation request

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I've my subscription observer registered as anonymous function in Azure (v2) to receive calendar events.Allow anonymous request is also enabled in Azure function (v2). I'm receiving the following error while subscribing despite the fact that the exact same code running locally using ngrok works.

```
Message: Subscription validation request failed. Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: 8ae23cdc-c35f-479c-89ee-00afed2230e4
    date: 2020-03-20T14:07:44
```

P.S: There's no request at receiver (observer) end.

Comment: Can you share your code? If you execute the subscription validation postman request in the misc folder of this collection what happens? (You can skip the part where you setup an application) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman

Comment: Hi Naveen, may I know if your problem was solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set "allow anonymous", so I think you need to check if your function can accept "text/plain" but not "application/json". Most of these issues are caused by the content-type.

You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965662/webhook-not-performing-subscription-validation) and this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_exchon-mso_o365b/not-able-to-create-calendar-events-webhook/da30f3c9-bf38-479a-958c-c69c4673b637).